# Could anyone help me with an SQL statement?

Tags: sql

Given is the following table:

```
aID | bID | idx
1   | 1   | 0
2   | 2   | 0
2   | 3   | 1
3   | 1   | 0
4   | 2   | 0
4   | 3   | 1
4   | 4   | 2
```

Is it possible to get the following outcome only using DELETE and UPDATE statements and not CURSORS?

```
aID | bID | idx
1   | 1   | 0
2   | 2   | 0
2   | 3   | 1
4   | 4   | 0
```

Each aID shall have a list of unique bIDs. The idx column just describes the order of the list.

I want to delete all multiple bIDs and only keep the bIDs with the lowest aID. And then update the idx for the remaining rows if needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You neglected to describe your logic, which we sort of need to answer your question.

Comment: what have you tried? which dbms is being used

Comment: Also, your title is your chance to summarize and "sell" your question to would-be answerers. At the moment, your title is so generic it could be applied to practically any question which is tagged [tag:sql]

Comment: I want to delete all multiple bIDs and only keep the bIDs with the lowest aID. And then update the idx for the remaining rows if needed.

Comment: OK...but I still don't get the `idx` part.  Can you explain why we see those 4 values in the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the job:

```
declare @t table (aID int, bID int, idx int)
insert into @t(aID,bID,idx) values
(1,1 ,0 ),
(2,2 ,0 ),
(2,3 ,1 ),
(3,1 ,0 ),
(4,2 ,0 ),
(4,3 ,1 ),
(4,4 ,2 )

delete
    t1
from @t t1
where exists (select * from @t t2 where t2.bID = t1.bID and t2.aID < t1.aID)

;With Numbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aID ORDER by bID) -1 as newIdx
    from @t
)
update Numbered set idx = newIdx

select * from @t
```

Once you've spelt out what you're requirements are in words, the logic of the queries flows quite naturally from that. Delete rows where theres another row with the same `bID` and a lower `aID` value.

Then `idx` is just the row numbers based on separate series for each `aID`. Of course, this does raise the question of why we're storing them at all when they can be so easily calculated<sup>1</sup>.

Result:

```
aID         bID         idx
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0
2           2           0
2           3           1
4           4           0
```

(Note that I've used SQL Server to test this - you didn't apply any product specific tags to the question - The table variable syntax is non-standard and the `delete ... from` is a bit questionable, but the rest is standard SQL)

---

<sup>1</sup>The general rule of thumb is to only store *base* data, not *derived* data. By separately storing derived data, you introduce the opportunity for the calculated values to be out-of-sync with the base data.

Second rule of thumb is if you do have to store derived data, ideally have the database engine take responsibility for maintaining it rather than yourself. But usually this is only if the calculation cost is prohibitively high and you're heavily biased towards readers rather than writers.

Answer (score 0):

use co-related sub-query

```
select t.* from your_table t 
where aID = (select min(aID) from your_table t1 
             where t1.bID=t.bID
            )
```